# Can I have two form's in diffrent places which triggers one request to server?

Tags: html

I am beginner to HTML. I found there is something like `form` which is used to pass data to server. I know what is the basic usage.

Last time I cut children of my initial `form` between two HTML files (some reorganization to include later in JSP). Personally I don't like to start tag `<form>` in one file, and close the `</form>` in other file. And I know I could do something like this (I will use this probably):

```
<form>
    // include file1
    // include file2
</form>
```

But now I am just thinking... Is it possible to do something totally different? like this:

```
    // first file
    <form name="input" action="index.html" method="get">
        <label for="iduser">User:</label><input id="iduser" type="text" name="user">
    </form>

    // second file
    <form name="input">
        <label for="iddata">Data:</label><input id="iddata" type="text" name="data">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I want to `submit` both inputs with button inside second form. I know above doesn't work even if I set the same `name` attribute. But maybe I missed something?

Comment: `name="input"` please don't do that.

Comment: `Data: <input ...>` please don't do that either. There's a label tag in html.

Comment: i might be wrong but im pretty sure you don't even need to five the form a formal name anymore.

Comment: I get this name from docu: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp . Any reason?

Comment: ohh.. `label` has something like `form_id` in HTML5. Maybe this is what I need.

Comment: w3schools is not associated with the actual w3c, the actual docu or better to say specification is to be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to break the form in 2 separate files, you can't have nested form elements so what you need to do is this

```
// first file
User: <input type="text" name="user">

// second file
Data: <input type="text" name="data">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: This was my first approach. I think this could be standard way to do that.

Comment: I would say this forms would be not nested but connected... If this is not possible it is OK than to combine this two separate files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to break it into seperate forms..

Keep it as the one form they will both be poosted to the same location..

```
// only File
<form name="input" action="index.html" method="post">
    <label>User:</label> <input type="text" name="user">
    <label>Data:</label> <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

if you wanted to carry on to the second page with the first page post values you could use something like php

```
<?php 

$value1FromPrevious = $_POST['user'];
$value2FromPrevious = $_POST['data'];

;?>
```

More HTML Code forms here

You will just need to change the form ACTION to your new php page..

Comment: I am using JSP not PHP. I described the reason why I need to cut this `inputs` in separate files. Some of them are optional so I can nicely manage this from JSP.